# Core Data database NSUnknownKeyException map location error

Tags: ios, core-data, nsunknownkeyexception

I've created an application in xcode that gets the location of a place from a user longclick on a map and inserte into a database. i keep getting this error

```
Travel Map Book[17935:3752754] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 
'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Locations 0x60800009f630> 
valueForUndefinedKey:]: the entity Locations is not key value coding-compliant 
for the key "longtitude".'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001065d2b0b 
__exceptionPreprocess + 171
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000102870141 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001065d2a59 -[NSException raise] + 9
3   CoreData                            0x0000000102de121b -[NSManagedObject valueForUndefinedKey:] + 299
4   Travel Map Book                     0x00000001021e04d7 _TFC15Travel_Map_Book19FirstViewController9fetchDatafT_T_ + 7159
5   Travel Map Book                     0x00000001021de18a _TFC15Travel_Map_Book19FirstViewController11viewDidLoadfT_T_ + 490
6   Travel Map Book                     0x00000001021de202 _TToFC15Travel_Map_Book19FirstViewController11viewDidLoadfT_T_ + 34
7   UIKit                               0x00000001036ab01a -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1235
8   UIKit                               0x00000001036e9e6c -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 56
9   UIKit                               0x00000001036ea74a -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 466
10  UIKit                               0x00000001036ea8bb -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 127
11  UIKit                               0x00000001036eba03 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 843
12  UIKit                               0x00000001036ecb41 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 58
13  UIKit                               0x00000001038de60c -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 231
14  UIKit                               0x00000001035cb55b -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1268
15  QuartzCore                          0x000000010b7bd904 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
16  QuartzCore                          0x000000010b7b1526 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 370
17  QuartzCore                          0x000000010b7b13a0 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
18  QuartzCore                          0x000000010b740e92 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 294
19  QuartzCore                          0x000000010b76d130 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 468
20  QuartzCore                          0x000000010b76db37 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 115
21  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106578717 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
22  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106578687 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
23  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010655d038 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 440
24  UIKit                               0x000000010350208f -[UIApplication _run] + 468
25  UIKit                               0x0000000103508134 UIApplicationMain + 159
26  Travel Map Book                     0x00000001021dd177 main + 55
27  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000106f9f65d start + 1
28  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
```

)
    libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)

I have tried cross-checking every spelling and data-type, still no luck with it. this is my fetchdata function

```
func fetchData(){
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Locations")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    do {
        let results = try context.fetch(request)
        if results.count > 0{
            self.titleArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
            self.subtitleArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
            self.longtitudeArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
            self.latitudeArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)


            for result in results as! [NSManagedObject]{
                if let title = result.value(forKey: "title") as? String{
                    self.titleArray.append(title)
                }
                if let subtitle = result.value(forKey: "subtitle") as? String{
                    self.subtitleArray.append(subtitle)
                }
                if let latitude = result.value(forKey: "latitude") as? Double{
                    self.latitudeArray.append(latitude)
                }
                if let longtitude = result.value(forKey: "longitude") as? Double{
                    self.longtitudeArray.append(longtitude)
                }

                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print("error")
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a core data issue. Look at your `fetchData` method.

Comment: The error message *the entity Locations is not key value coding-compliant 
for the key "longtitude"* is quite meaningful. Looks like a typo `long-t-itude`

Comment: Thanks, found it. was a typo